# Why can't I see worker counts anymore?

Tags: starcraft-2

I can no longer see how many workers are assigned to my extractors or how many are assigned to gather minerals. I've already reset everything back to default. I get blank boxes over my buildings where this information used to be.

Comment: Ok, so if anyone else ever has the same issue. Just reset all your gameplay and UI's to default and then close out and relaunch the program. My settings were set back to default and that did work but only after relaunching the program so it could make the changes.  Peace out, hope this helps others.  -Orion

Comment: You should probably post the above comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite sure that there is a setting for that.

You have to go to Settings > Gameplay: it is either "Always show worker status" or "Show current order indicator".

Since I don't have SC2 installed at the moment I cannot test it. (Ignore the red box in the following screenshot).

---

[image: Ignore the red box]